# NodeJS 16 started installing additional packages and does not come with npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Today I discovered that my long used nodejs installation started failing because it does no include npm anymore.

I started investigating and noticed strange and different things in my build logs.

My node installation goes as follows:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
```

^^ Output from this seems to be fine as it was earlier.

```
apt install -y nodejs
```

^^ Output of this install is different, it doesn't install npm and it seems that it's fetching nodejs v. 18:

```
Runner
Build setup
14s
cd /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src
<1s
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
<1s
apt update && apt install -yq curl openssh-client gettext-base rsync
15s
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
9s
apt install -y nodejs
7s
+ apt install -y nodejs
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-12-base libc-ares2 libicu72 libnode108 libstdc++6 libuv1 node-acorn
  node-busboy node-cjs-module-lexer node-undici node-xtend nodejs-doc
Suggested packages:
  npm
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-12-base libc-ares2 libicu72 libnode108 libuv1 node-acorn node-busboy
  node-cjs-module-lexer node-undici node-xtend nodejs nodejs-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libstdc++6
1 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 78 not upgraded.
Need to get 24.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 106 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 gcc-12-base amd64 12.2.0-14 [37.5 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 libstdc++6 amd64 12.2.0-14 [614 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 libc-ares2 amd64 1.18.1-3 [102 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 libicu72 amd64 72.1-3 [9376 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 libuv1 amd64 1.44.2-1 [140 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 node-xtend all 4.0.2-3 [3932 B]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 nodejs amd64 18.13.0+dfsg1-1 [304 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 node-acorn all 8.8.1+ds+~cs25.17.7-2 [128 kB]
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 node-cjs-module-lexer all 1.2.2+dfsg-5 [30.1 kB]
Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 node-busboy all 1.6.0+~cs2.6.0-2 [16.9 kB]
Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 node-undici all 5.15.0+dfsg1+~cs20.10.9.3-1 [283 kB]
Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 libnode108 amd64 18.13.0+dfsg1-1 [10.3 MB]
Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 nodejs-doc all 18.13.0+dfsg1-1 [3358 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 24.7 MB in 1s (40.1 MB/s)
```

Output from the same command was different few days ago:

```
+ apt-get install -yq nodejs
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 128 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x bullseye/main amd64 nodejs amd64 16.20.0-deb-1nodesource1 [27.2 MB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 27.2 MB in 1s (21.6 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 8679 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_16.20.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (16.20.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
Setting up nodejs (16.20.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
```

No server configuration was changed.
I tried running a local docker container of ubuntu 20 and do the same - it installs everything as expected.

Maybe someone could tip me to the right direction about what might have happened?

Thank you

Tried installing node 16 with npm. It installs different version, a bunch of additional packages and no npm.

Comment: Apparently the image I use for my builds - **debian:stable-slim** has been updated to bullseye from buster and it started acting this way. I still don't understand this behaviour but changing image name to **debian:buster-slim** returned things to normal. I guess we need to update our builds more often.